# The search filter cannot be recognized

Tags: powershell

i am trying to validate users input by using `Do-until` 
i want the program to keep looping until a valid input has been given, that is working when the users gives any input regardless of what it is, but when the value is empty `""` i get stuck in an endless loop that keeps giving me this error

```
The user does exist in AD:
samaccountname: 'the username'
Full Name: 'the fullname'  

get-aduser : The search filter cannot be recognized
At line:6 char:9
+ $user = get-aduser -Filter "samaccountname -eq '$SiteOwner' -OR name  -eq '$SiteO ...
+         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Get-ADUser], ADException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : ActiveDirectoryServer:8254,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.GetADUser
```

this is my code:

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
Do{

$SiteOwner = Read-Host 'OwnerAlias'

Do {
$user = get-aduser -Filter "samaccountname -eq '$SiteOwner' -OR name -eq '$SiteOwner'"
If (!$user) {
  "The user does not exist in AD"
} 
Else {
"The user does exist in AD:`nsamaccountname: $($user.samaccountname)`nFull Name: $($user.name)"
}



}While (($null -eq $SiteOwner) -or ( "" -eq $SiteOwner))
}Until ($user)
```

what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a version of your code that works:

```
# Ensure variables are null - may not be needed, depending on the rest of your code (if any)
$user = $null
$SiteOwner = $null

# Assuming $user is null we should do a lookup
while(-not $user) {
    $SiteOwner = Read-Host 'OwnerAlias'

    # As long as the user entered some text, query AD - otherwise, skip this and ask again
    if (-not [string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($SiteOwner)) {
        $user = Get-AdUser -Filter "samaccountname -eq '$SiteOwner' -OR name -eq '$SiteOwner'"

        if (-not $user) {
          # Found the user - we should exit the while
          "The user does not exist in AD"
        } 
        else {
          # Didn't find the user - ask for the name again
          "The user does exist in AD:`nsamaccountname: $($user.samaccountname)`nFull Name: $($user.name)"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that with `""` as the input, it is throwing a terminating error. You can account for that with a `try-catch` block. Inside of that, you can add a break statement to break out of the second `do-until` loop. This could probably be designed differently though.

```
Do{

  $SiteOwner = Read-Host 'OwnerAlias'

  Do {
    try {
      $user = get-aduser -Filter "samaccountname -eq '$SiteOwner' -OR name -eq '$SiteOwner'"
    }
    catch {
      "The user does not exist in AD"
      break
    }
    If (!$user) {
      "The user does not exist in AD"
    } 
    Else {
      "The user does exist in AD:`nsamaccountname: $($user.samaccountname)`nFull Name: $($user.name)"
    }

  }While (($null -eq $SiteOwner) -or ( "" -eq $SiteOwner))
}Until ($user)
```

Comment: thanks for the reply, you're right but i chose the approach that i was able to understand the most, your solution worked perfectly, thank you again!

Comment: i just have a small question, is there a difference between ($null -eq $SiteOwner) and ($SiteOwner -eq $null ) or does it give the same result?

Comment: @user11124311.  Yes, this can sometimes lead to problems, so it is best practice to put `$null` on the left of the comparison: [PossibleIncorrectComparisonWithNull](https://github.com/PowerShell/PSScriptAnalyzer/blob/development/RuleDocumentation/PossibleIncorrectComparisonWithNull.md)

Comment: Yes, there is a difference. If $null is on the right side, PowerShell will check to see if the variable contains a null value. So if you have an array as a variable, it will check each element of the array and it will just return $null regardless. Having $null on the left side will verify if the variable is actually $null.

Comment: @boxdog, Interesting, will do                                                                                                       thank you for replying!